# Can't pass an array to the From trait with a slice of arbitrary length

Tags: rust

I'm trying to implement `From<&[&str]>` for one of my types. It should consume an arbitrary length of lines (only known during runtime) and fetches data from the lines. The compiler complains about that `&[&str; 2]` is not `&[&str]`, i.e. it can't convert a fixed-size slice to one with arbitrary length. The exact message is: `the trait 'From<&[&str; 2]>' is not implemented for 'LineEater'`

This is my attempt:

```rust
fn main() {
    let data = ["foo", "bar"];
    
    // works
    foo(&data);

    // doesn't work
    LineEater::from(&data);

    // also doesn't work
    let data: &[&str] = data.into();
    LineEater::from(&data);
}

struct LineEater;
impl From<&[&str]> for LineEater {
    fn from(_lines: &[&str]) -> Self {
        todo!()
    }
}

fn foo(_slice: &[&str]) {}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3e9bf81e66a90945e7618e3946de2777)

It's confusing that this works with the call of `foo()` but not the call of `from`. In the first case Rust can "cast" the `[&str; 2]` to `&[&str]` but not in the latter. Why is this so and how can I fix it?

I'm working with Rust 1.55-nightly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the range operator:

```rust
fn main() {
    let data = ["foo", "bar"];
    LineEater::from(&data[..]);
}

struct LineEater;
impl From<&[&str]> for LineEater {
    fn from(_lines: &[&str]) -> Self {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=837262b0e287bc0d7d98051e1307645e)

Or you can use the fully qualified syntax to tell Rust that you want to use the `From` implementation for `&[&str]`:

```rust
fn main() {
    let data = ["foo", "bar"];
    <LineEater as From<&[&str]>>::from(&data);
}

struct LineEater;
impl From<&[&str]> for LineEater {
    fn from(_lines: &[&str]) -> Self {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c85fd165e09b7b73904079cfb3245860)

Comment: The `AsRef::as_ref` and `Borrow::borrow` methods can also perform the conversion, as well as casting with `as` (`&data as &[&str]`).

Answer (score 1):

You need to coerce your array into an slice:

```rust
let data: &[&str] = &["foo", "bar"];
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fcff71ca5a599b716c5e296592db3f88)

Check out also the first example in the [slice documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/index.html)